# c# devexpress chart how to get data

Tags: c#, charts, devexpress

I want to fill the chart from database with code.(please do not suggest me choose chart and click Add datasource) I have tried some codes.but I cannot receive any values and any data.here is the codes ;

```
public DataTable Rating() {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MEVLUT\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Chart;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from ChannelRatings", conn);
        DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ChartControl ch = chartcontrolRatings;
        Series series = new Series("Ratings",ViewType.Bar);
        ch.Series.Add(series);
        series.DataSource = Rating();
        this.Controls.Add(ch);
    }
```

2 columns ChannelName and RatingValue and they have values.

Comment: I update my answer with chart example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I think of is that  ExecuteReader did not execute. I will post some example

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from ChannelRatings";
cmd.Connection = dbConnection;
    SqlDataReader dr= null;
    using (dr= cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
          DataTable dtData = new DataTable(storedProcedureName);
          //First create Columns for new DataTable
          object[] values = new object[dr.FieldCount];
          Type[] columnTypes = new Type[dr.FieldCount];
          for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
          {
            Type columnType = dr.GetFieldType(i);
            string columnName = dr.GetName(i);
            if (columnType != null)
            {
              dtData.Columns.Add(columnName, columnType);
              columnTypes[i] = columnType;
            }
          }
          t1 = DateTime.Now.Subtract(d1);
          while (dr.Read())
          {//Fill DataTable by reading values by type...
            int columnsRead = dr.GetValues(values);
            DataRow newRow = dtData.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < dtData.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
              if (columnTypes[i].Name == "Int32") newRow[i] = values[i] != null && values[i] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(values[i]) : Base.BussinesLayer.Utils.Int32NullValue;
              else if (columnTypes[i].Name == "Int16") newRow[i] = values[i] != null && values[i] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt16(values[i]) : Base.BussinesLayer.Utils.Int16NullValue;
              else if (columnTypes[i].Name == "String") newRow[i] = values[i] != null && values[i] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(values[i]) : Base.BussinesLayer.Utils.StringNullValue;
              else if (columnTypes[i].Name == "Decimal") newRow[i] = values[i] != null && values[i] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDecimal(values[i]) : Base.BussinesLayer.Utils.DecimalNullValue;
              else if (columnTypes[i].Name == "DateTime") newRow[i] = values[i] != null && values[i] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDateTime(values[i]) : Base.BussinesLayer.Utils.DateTimeNullValue;
              else if (columnTypes[i].Name == "TimeSpan") newRow[i] = values[i] != null && values[i] != DBNull.Value ? EvotechUtils.ConvertToTimeSpan(values[i]) : Base.BussinesLayer.Utils.DateTimeNullValue.TimeOfDay;
              else if (columnTypes[i].Name == "Int64") newRow[i] = values[i] != null && values[i] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt64(values[i]) : Base.BussinesLayer.Utils.Int64NullValue;
              else if (columnTypes[i].Name == "Float") newRow[i] = values[i] != null && values[i] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt64(values[i]) : Base.BussinesLayer.Utils.FloatNullValue;
              else if (columnTypes[i].Name == "Double") newRow[i] = values[i] != null && values[i] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt64(values[i]) : Base.BussinesLayer.Utils.DoubleNullValue;
              else if (columnTypes[i].Name == "Byte") newRow[i] = values[i] != null && values[i] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt64(values[i]) : Base.BussinesLayer.Utils.ByteNullValue;
              else newRow[i] = DBNull.Value;
            }
            dtData.Rows.Add(newRow);
          }
          dr.Close();                                   
    }
```

Chart example :

```
        chcGraph.BeginInit();
        chcGraph.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;          
        chcGraph.Series.Add("GraphSeriesMain", ViewType.Pie);
        chcGraph.Series.Swap(chcGraph.Series[0], chcGraph.Series["GraphSeriesMain"]);
        chcGraph.Series["GraphSeriesMain"].DataSource = dataTableData;
        chcGraph.Series["GraphSeriesMain"].ArgumentDataMember = "ChannelName";
        chcGraph.Series["GraphSeriesMain"].ArgumentScaleType = ScaleType.Qualitative;
        chcGraph.Series["GraphSeriesMain"].ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "RatingValue" });
        chcGraph.EndInit();
        chcGraph.Refresh();
```

Comment: I didn't use your first code.I have tried with your chart Example and it works..No need for ExecuteReader or sqlcommand.But I have a question,the pie says me %percents of my values.How can I show A channel B channel C channel for the colours?

Comment: What type chart you need? Pie,Bar,Line??? You can change it when creating Series : ViewType. Chart use for Default Color and you can change it by :                 chcGraph.PaletteName = "Nature Colors"; // "Urban" //"Trek" "The Trees" "Technics"

Comment: Or please precisely write what you need.

Comment: No no.I mean there is a pie which has 3 colours.And top right of the chart.Red colour %67 yellow colour %23 blue colour %10..Can I change the top right and can I give a name like A,B,C which are my Channel names

Comment: If you need to change the text in the legend, so try this event:
`chGraph_CustomDrawSeriesPoint (object sender, CustomDrawSeriesPointEventArgs e)
DataTable dtData = (DataTable) e.Series.DataSource; if (dtData! = null) {DataRow [] rows = dtData.Select ("ChanelName =" + e.SeriesPoint.Argument); if (rows! = null && rows.Length == 1) {e.LegendText = rows [0] ["ChanelName"]. ToString (); }}`

Comment: an error occurs on dtData.Select ("ChanelName =" + e.SeriesPoint.Argument) and says Column 'A' did not found. 'A' is my channel name.

Comment: So change the select the for the table. Try  "ChanelName = '" + e.SeriesPoint.Argument + "'"

Comment: So you'll have to more explore and debug your code. I can not help more.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to bind your data to a Pivot Grid, and then bind the pivot grid to the Chart.  In the `BindingSource` for your chart, you actually select the drop-down and pick the Pivot Grid.

This has the advantage of allowing you to work with the pivot grid at design time (and even run-time) to modify the chart to your exact liking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the Winforms or WPF version of this components?

I only have experience witch the WPF version and I am not sure how much the WinFormas version differ.

But at the WPF Version I have to set the Values `ArgumentDataMember` and `ValueDataMember` of my series(template) to specify what columns of my DataTable contain the Argument and Value Data.

So if it is the WPF Chart you have to add something like:

```
series.ArgumentDataMember = "ChanelName";
series.ValueDataMember = "Rating";
```

regards

Comment: I use Winforms which does not contain series.ValueDataMember.there is series.ValueDataMembers and it is read only...I have to use series.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(params string[]) ? I think,no